# 1px solid border under my maps in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, border

I have this issue in IE6 where I cannot seem to get rid of a 2px border at the bottom of this map - http://bit.ly/g5kn4K.

In all other browsers, I have managed to sort this out including IE7 where it was happening too.

In IE7, I set a height for the wrapper around the map and this sorted out the issue, but IE6 doesn't like this. In fact, IE6 is allergic to the web.

Thanks ;)

Comment: How critical is it for you to support IE6 perfectly? My recommendation is to just shrug your shoulders and say that for IE6 users, this is good enough. As you say, IE6 has major issues that make it hard to write code that works for both it and other browsers. IE6 also has *very* low usage figures now (<3% in most major developed countries), and the issue you describe sounds pretty minor and doesn't prevent the user from actually doing anything, so why not let them just live with it. If nothing else it'll give them incentive to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Might be the way you are applying the border. You have the following:

```
.imageMapWrapper img { padding: 10px; background-color: #F6F6F6; }
```

Removing the inline style on that tag, and change the CSS with the following:

```
.imageMapWrapper img { 10px solid #F6F6F6; }
```